# Function from a higher dimension to a lower one

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

It is a general thought so I hope it make any sense, it the case of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we could talk about onto and isomorphic map. is it the same with  $g:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $h:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$

do not we "lose" data going from an higher dimension to a smaller one?

Comment: Such a map can be onto ("surjective"), but it cannot be one-to-one ("injective") or isomorphic ("bijective").